# Convertir cadena numérica con coma en fecha SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

necesito convertir una cadena numérica con coma en fecha en una base de datos. El valor me llega en el siguiente formato

```
   44794,539583333 -> Corresponde a 21-08-2022 12:57:00 Segun formato fecha en excel
   44794,515277778 -> Corresponde a 21-08-2022 12:22:00 Segun formato fecha en excel
   44794,725       -> Corresponde a 21-08-2022 17:24:00 Segun formato fecha en excel
```

He descubierto que los digitos antes de la coma corresponden a la cantidad de dias en relacion a la fecha 1899-30-12.
pero no he podido calcular la hora en el formato hh:mm:ss
he intentado usando to_char de la siguiente forma:

```
select to_char(valor/3600, 'FM9900') || ':' ||
       to_char(mod(valor,3600/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
       to_char(mod(valor/,60),'FM00')
from dual
```

Comment: El tema es que representa la parte "decimal" por que no parecen que fueran segundos ni milisegundos

Answer (score 0):

El número que obtienes de excel puedes sumarlo directamente a la fecha base, que  es el 30 de diciembre de 1899 `1899-12-30`, pues Oracle representa las fechas de una manera similar internamente y el tipo de dato `date` soporta aritmética con números.

```
declare
  miFecha date;
begin
  miFecha := to_date('1899-12-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + 44794.539583333;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(miFecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'));
end;
/
```

Produce la salida:

```
Statement processed.
21/08/2022 12:57:00
```

Por otro lado, y para responder a

> pero no he podido calcular la hora en el formato hh:mm:ss

La parte fraccionaria representa la proporción del día que ha transcurrido desde la media noche. Digamos, el porcentaje del día. Así, podemos obtener los datos convirtiendo esta fracción al número total de segundos transcurridos multiplicando 86400 segundos que tiene el día por la parte fraccionaria del número, en tu ejemplo, 0.539583333.

Luego, este número total de segundos lo podemos convertir a horas, minutos y segundos haciendo la matemática habitual de conversión:

```
declare
  FechaExcel float := 44794.539583333;
  FraccionDia float;
  SegundosTotales integer;
  hh integer;
  mi integer;
  ss integer;
begin
  FraccionDia := FechaExcel - trunc(FechaExcel);
  SegundosTotales := Round(FraccionDia * 86400, 0);
  hh := SegundosTotales / 3600;
  mi := mod(SegundosTotales, 3600) / 60;
  ss := mod(SegundosTotales, 60);
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(hh, 'FM00')||':'||to_char(mi, 'FM00')||':'||to_char(ss, 'FM00'));
end;
/
```

Esto imprime:

```
Statement processed.
12:57:00
```